# $AA^{-1} =I $ and $A^{-1}=E_{1}\dots E_{n}A$ does this prove that $\det(E_{1}\dots E_{n}) = \det(1/A^{2})$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I was answering a question on a test and I happened by this.

$AA^{-1} = I$

and $A^{-1} = E_{1}\dots E_{n}A$

from the first I know that $\det(A^{-1})= \det(1/A)$

from the second I know that $\det(A^{-1}) = \det(E_{1}\dots E_{n})\cdot\det(A)$

Have i made a mistake or does this mean that the elementary row operation required to change $A$ to $A^{-1}$ have the determinat equal to $\det(1/A^{2})$

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: wow, i'm so chuffed. Figured this out by accident on a linear algebra midterm

Comment: What does $1/A^2$ mean if $A$ is a matrix?

Comment: It's fine, except that we generally write $A^{-2}$ rather than $1/A^2$ when $A$ is a matrix.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Are you using the "royal we" here?

Comment: is the reciprocal of a matrix the same as the inverse?

Comment: "We" as in mathematicians.

Comment: @ConradG That's how it must be interpreted for your statement to make sense.